# iMovie - how to create video with real size of all photos?

Tags: mac, video, osx-lion, imovie

I have a lot of photos from vacations and I wanted to make a video with music from them. I used iMovie, put there photos + music I like and then I ran the video. Everything was working great except one thing - the photos weren't displayed whole.

It looks like iMovie cropped the images... so, for example, on one photos is missing its top, on the second one its bottom etc.

Is there any way to setup in iMovie to display always the whole size of photos?